# Moving images into folders with image filename

Tags: bash, directory, mkdir

I have a folder called folder1 that has a bunch of pictures in it, and I would like to save each picture in an individual folder. The folder should have the same name as the file, for example if the picture is called "st123" I would like to create a folder called "st123" and move the picture into the folder. I have tried the following, but I get the error cannot move to a subdirectory of itself. Is there another way to solve this?
Otherwise, would it be possible to save the image "st123" in a folder called "123" (so the last 3 characters)?

```
#!/bin/bash
Parent="/home/me/myfiles/folder1"
for file in $Parent; do
dir="${file%%.*}"
mkdir -p "$dir"
mv "$file" "$dir" 
done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution might be useful to you, though if you'd like to iterate over the images **recursively** I suggest you to use `find`. If that's indeed the case, let me know and I'll edit this answer with relevant code.

```
for image in /home/me/myfiles/folder1/*; do
    if [[ -f $image ]]; then 
        newf="${image%%?([ab]).*}"
        mkdir -p "$newf"
        mv -- "$image" "$newf"
    fi
done
```

Test ( *extglob* is enabled ):

```
$ [/home/rany/] touch test/st123a.tif test/st123b.tif test/st456.jpg test/st456b.jpg test/st789.tif
$ [/home/rany/] for image in test/*; do newf="${image%%?([ab]).*}"; mkdir -p "$newf"; mv -- "$image" "$newf";done
$ [/home/rany/] tree test
test
├── st123
│   ├── st123a.tif
│   └── st123b.tif
├── st456
│   ├── st456b.jpg
│   └── st456.jpg
└── st789
    └── st789.tif

3 directories, 5 files
```

## EDIT:

According to OP request I added the following changes:

- Trim file-name's suffix `a` or `b`, so that, for example, file names *st123a.ext* and *st123b.ext* will go to the same directory *st123*. **Important**: this feature requires *[extglob](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob#extglob)* enabled ( i.e. `shopt -s extglob` ).

Comment: This worked, thanks. Additionally, if I have two pictures for example "st123a" and "st123b", is it also possible to move these into the same subdirectory called "st123" ?

Comment: You're welcome! Yes, I edited my answer to include this behavior.

Comment: Unfortunately I am getting the errors
`mkdir: cannot create directory '/home/(..)/folder1/st123a': File exists` and
`mv: '/home/(..)/folder1/st123a' and '/home/(..)/folder1/st123a' are the same file` 
for files a and b, despite running `shopt -s extglob` before running the code

Comment: I suspect that your files does not contain any extension (e.g. st123a.jpg ). Am I correct?

Comment: it has a .tif extension, but even when rename it without the extension, I was getting the same error

Comment: I added a test. See if that's what you're doing.

Comment: yes this is what I am doing, except I have it in a bash script and calling it with `bash myCode.sh`

Comment: You're running the script multiple times and things starts to collide. Let's add another `if` statement before any actions are made, to be sure that `image` is indeed a regular file. Edited my answer. It will be helpful to see your directory `tree`.

Comment: I tried to run the tree and get the following result:
`test [error opening dir]
0 directories, 0 files`
However it still runs and organizes the folders as I would like, however only when I run it from terminal

Comment: Sounds like your directory is not executable. Try to `chmod +x test` and go again.

Comment: great that fixed the problem when running from terminal, now it's showing me a proper tree. However I still get the exact same error as before when I try to run it from a script, although I'm using the exact same commands (except my script has the `#!/bin/bash` )

Comment: Can you please [sprunge](http://sprunge.us) the script you're executing so we can be sure?

Comment: Sorry I'm having a hard time with sprunge as I keep getting an empty link. Here is my code, in my home directory, called: folder.sh 
`#!/bin/bash
for image in /home/me/results/folder1/*; do
     if [[ -f $image ]]; then
         subdir="${image%%?([ab]).*}"
         mkdir -p "$subdir"
         mv -- "$image" "$subdir"
     fi
done`
I have 4 spaces as indents and running it using bash folder.sh

Comment: You didn't enable extglob inside your script. A non-interactive shell is being executed to run your script, in which extglob is disabled, therefore `subdir` doesn't contain the correct name.

Comment: Ah okay, I just ran the extglob command before running my script. Now it's working correctly, thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 1):

You almost have it working! Change part of line 3 so the for loop iterates over what's inside the directory instead of the directory itself:

```
#!/bin/bash
Parent="/home/me/myfiles/folder1"
for file in $Parent/*; do
dir="${file%%.*}"
mkdir -p "$dir"
mv "$file" "$dir" 
done
```

https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html#Command-Substitution

Comment: Yes, you should use find (and perl as you state in your link!). I edited the answer to reflect this.  The op doesn't state what kind of images, *.jpg likely won't be effective, and *.{jpg,JPG,jpeg,JPEG,png,svg,.....} is still likely to miss something in a varied set of images.

Comment: Never do this: `for x in $(command)` or `\`command\`` or `$var`. for-in is used for iterating arguments, not (output) strings. Instead, use a glob (eg. `*.txt`), arrays (eg. `"${names[@]}"`) or a while-read 
                loop (eg. `while read -r line`). See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#pf1 and http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor

Comment: Moreover, you're using `find`'s `-print0`, which is in this case not only useless, but just plain wrong.